# Trying to enter records into a mysql database using vb.net but its not working and I cant figure out why

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Mysql is connected to my vb so thats not the problem Im not really sure whats wrong.

This is a register account form, im using xampp for mysql.

Public Class Reigsteraccount

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim WithEvents Button1 As New Button
    Dim WithEvents Textbox1 As New TextBox
    Dim WithEvents Textbox2 As New TextBox
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=compproject"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader


        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into compproject.users (Usernames,Passwordhash) values ('" & Textbox1.Text & "','" & Textbox2.Text & "')"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader


            MessageBox.Show("Record added")
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure the password is `root`? By default it's usually blank.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's some very bad code - I know this isn't CodeReview, but still, it needs to be pointed out!  Have a look at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you want to brush up on best practices (I appreciate you might be a first time coder...).

To answer the question, you are using `COMMAND.ExecuteReader` - this should be replaced with `COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery`.  You're not reading from the database, you're writing data into it (INSERT command in the SQL).

If it still doesn't work after changing that, please update your question to include more detail, such as the exception generated, etc.

Comment: Thank you, when I press the button to insert the value it didn't even give my the exception message it just did nothing, I will change the code and see if anything changes.

Comment: You're only catching `MySQLException`s.  Add another catch clause for plain old `Exception`s and see what that gives you.